# Are type constructors always injectives even in presence of quantified type variables (subtyping)?

Tags: type-theory, java

Are type constructors, in a language that feature subtyping and quantification of type variables, like scala or Java, always injective?

That is, is an equivalent of haskell `lower` function, as seen [here](https://github.com/ekmett/eq/blob/master/src/Data/Eq/Type.hs#L114), safe in such a language? (even if the implementation use typecasting)

```haskell
#ifdef LANGUAGE_TypeFamilies
type family Inj f
type instance Inj (f a) = a
newtype Lower a b = Lower { unlower :: Inj a := Inj b }
-- | Type constructors are injective, so you can lower equality through any type constructor
lower :: f a := f b -> a := b
lower eq = unlower (subst eq (Lower refl :: Lower (f a) (f a)))
```

By quantified type variables I mean, eg. for java:

```java
class F<T extends F<T>> {}

class G<T extends F<? super G<T>>> extends F<G<T>>{}
```

Where `G` and `F` are type constructors and `T` is a (quantified) type variable.
In the above context the question become:

For every types `A` and `B`, if we know that the types `G<A>` and `G<B>` are the same type (in the sense of leibnizian equality), can we safely conclude that `A` and `B` are the same type?

Subsidiary question: If we cannot generally conclude on type constructor injectivity (eg. due to weird properties of subtyping), what are the properties that type variables must satisfy to guarantee injectivity?

This is a practical question in the context of [implementing Leibniz equality for Java](https://github.com/derive4j/hkt/pull/19).

Comment: Please edit your question to make it self-contained, so we can understand what you are asking without following external links (and so the question will continue to make sense even if the link stops working).  (As a kindness to readers, you might also want to include in the question the definition of what it means for a constructor to be injective, and what you mean by "Leibniz equality".)

Comment: I think this question should be made language-agnostic in order to be ontopic here. Community votes, please!

Comment: I disagree. Whether a language has some feature depends on the language, obviously. There's no real point in switching from Java to "nominal type class hierachy with single inheritance", unless we're shooting for not being indexed by Google.

Comment: Could you give an example of a *type constructor* in Java? The Java type system is not exactly the same thing as the Haskell type system, so we should first establish what you mean by "type constructor" in Java (in Haskell it is clear).

Comment: @Raphael I think it's fine to ask about type theory as it applies to Java. I think it's a question about the relationship between the theory and the "real world" rather than, say, a programming question.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Questions about Java are offtopic here. Question about how CS concepts appear in Java can be ontopic, but the titular question seems to be of the former kind.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think the two questions have different qualities. The first (the titular one) is offtopic, I think, while the second ("How can I express X using [the type system of] Y?" can be ontopic.

Comment: I think they are injective, but there's no way to write `lower` in Java since it lacks higher kinds (how would you write `forall f.`?). In Scala this could be doable.

Comment: @chi: the https://github.com/derive4j/hkt aims to provide higher kinded types for java.